# Did the EU successfully ban hydrazine? What about French Guiana?

Tags: launch, safety, esa, regulatory, hydrazine

[Hobbes' answer to *Is the EU really banning “toxic propellants” in 2020? How is that going to work?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37869/12102) includes

> Yes, the EU is aiming to end the use of hydrazine by ~2020. This has been in motion since about 2011.
>
> [ESA's strategy do deal with this](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Safety/Clean_Space/Considering_hydrazine-free_satellite_propulsion) consists of two parts:
>
> 1. they're trying to get an exemption,
> 2. they're working on alternatives, inviting industry to develop propulsion systems based on less toxic propellants.

and

> As of 2019, the [exemption is still being discussed](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Engineering_Technology/ESA_responding_to_EU_s_REACH_chemical_law).

**Question:** This is now 2021 and change, how did it go? Did the EU successfully ban the use of hydrazine? If so, for launches in which locations? What about [French Guiana?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37867) (or don't they count?)

Comment: From the research I've done so far, it looks like "hydrazine" is still on the SVHC candidate list, but has not yet made it onto the REACH restriction list.  That would seem to indicate that the ban still has yet to be enacted, although an EU resident/aficionado could provide more detail...

Comment: Yeah from what I’ve seen, the only articles on the hydrazine ban is from the early 2010s-2020. However I’d keep this question up in case in the future something comes up.

Comment: Given that French Guiana, like all it other overseas territories are an integral part of France, one would assume both French & [European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Guiana#/media/File:EU_OCT_and_OMR_map_en.png) laws would apply there, unless there was an exemption for that particular location.

Comment: @Fred there's discussion of that on the page I link to, though I'm not sure if there's any conclusion there.